# Why this linked list program to insert a node at the end is not giving any output?

Tags: c++, c++17

This code is not giving any output.
There can be different ways to implement linked list. But I want to find my error in this one.
I can't find any error in this code.
Here is my complete code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;

    node(int val){
      data=val;
      next=NULL;
    }
 };

 void insertAtTail (node* &head, int val){
   node * n=new node(val);
   
   if(head==NULL){
     head=n;
   }
   node * temp= head;
   while(temp->next != NULL){
     temp=temp->next;
   }
   temp->next=n;

 }

void display(node* head){
  node * temp= head;
  while(temp!=NULL){
    cout<<temp->data<< "->";
    temp=temp->next;
  }
  cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
}

 int main(){
   node *head=NULL;
   insertAtTail(head,1);
   insertAtTail(head,2);
   insertAtTail(head,3);
   display(head);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What did you observe whe you stepped through your cod line by line with the debugger?

Comment: The debugger isn't supposed to show errors. You probably confuse that with the _compiiler_.

Comment: What is `node`? What does its constructor do? How does the constructor initialize the cobject? Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve].

Comment: added complete code

Comment: You're missing an else (or return) in the initial head assignment aftermath of insertAtTail. After assigning head, it *then* assigns the same node to itself, which results in a circular linked list of one node. The next insert will spin forever because `next` is never null. An alternative, btw: [here](https://pastebin.com/CKvsKxfS).

Comment: The lesson for today: Learn how to use a *debugger* (or just general debugging techniques, like [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)). Using a debugger you would have found out the problem quite quickly. Being able to debug your programs is a crucial skill to learn and know.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes I will learn it today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to find my error in this one.

Following step by step of your `insertAtTail` function, you'll find that your `head` and your `head->next` pointers are pointing to the same memory location.
After assigning your initial `head` pointer you are assigning the same value to the `next` node.

A simple fix to your code is to return after initializing the head.

```
void insertAtTail(node*& head, const int val) {
  node* n = new node(val);
   
  if(head==nullptr){
    head=n;
    return;  // head is initialized, we don't need to do more here
  }
  node* temp= head;
  while(temp->next != nullptr){
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  temp->next = n;
}
```

An alternative way to implement this function is

```
void insertAtTailRec(node*& head, const int val) {
  if(head == nullptr) {
    head = new node(val);
    return;
  }
  insertAtTailRec(head->next, val);
}
```

Or the solution pointed out by @WhozCraig. I suggest you experiment with different ways to implement this function.